# Contact form inputs fade out and fade in

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Hello i am creating contact form which have four inputs name,phone,email,message I want when I click the single input then another one will be fade 30% like email, phone, message and if I click another one then another one will be fade 30% and if I filled the inputs that inputs looks not faded.

```
<div class="contact-form ss-map">
                        <h1>Message</h1>
                        <form action="" method="post" id="validateForm">
                            <div class="form-group error">
                                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="" area-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="" area-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" required="" area-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" required="" area-required="true">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <a href="#" class="link link-green center submit-btn"><span>Start the conversation</span></a>
                                <!-- <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start the conversation"> -->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <p class="copyright d-none d-sm-block">Copyright @ 2018 JGM</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: where is your code,what problem do you have?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, which is *"a little bit different from other sites"*; please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [how to ask an On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).... a.k.a what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: sounds like some simple css would solve this

Answer (score 1):

Here.

Set `opacity` for the clicked input to 1 and others to 0.7 (fade 30%).

```js
$(".fade-others-on-click").click(function(){
  $(this).css('opacity', '1')
  $(".fade-others-on-click").not($(this)).css('opacity', '0.7')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="fade-others-on-click">
<input class="fade-others-on-click">
<input class="fade-others-on-click">
<input class="fade-others-on-click">
```

Comment: if i select other one so other one will be opacity 1 and all inputs fade 30%?

Comment: The one you selected will have opacity as 1 and the other inputs (in the same class, as for this example) will be transparent with opacity 0.7, which is I think is acceptable for your "fade 30%". You can run the code snippet to see if it really is what you want.

Comment: its working fine but if i click body block it should be display same opacity like 1

Answer (score 0):

For that problem, you can use CSS [:focus](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) selector with combination [:not](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_not.asp) selector.

**If you wanna example code, please comment.**

Comment: Hello i am creating contact form which have four inputs name,phone,email,message I want when I click the single input then another one will be fade 30% like email, phone, message and if I click another one then another one will be fade 30% and if I filled the inputs that inputs looks not faded.

Comment: https://codepen.io/miloshn-the-sans/pen/NoOXeK?editors=1100

Comment: <script>$('#validateForm').click(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val == ''){
     $("input").focus($(this)).css('opacity', '1');
     $('.form-control').not(this).css("opacity", "0.3");
     $('.form-control').each(function(){
      var val1 = $(this).val();
      if(val1 != ''){
         $(this).css("opacity", "1");
      }
    });
  }
$("body").change(function(){
  $(".form-control").blur($(this)).css('opacity', '1');
});
});</script>

Comment: i am adding that script but still there is some problem that when click input field it should be opacity 1